# C# snippet starting up directly environment variables window is not working on Windows 10

Tags: c#, environment-variables, windows-10, rundll32

I've been using the following piece of code to directly open the Environment variables screen with a single button click:

```
private void OpenEnvVariables()
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "rundll32.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables";
    p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p.Start();
}
```

It was working just fine up until the moment I ran my tooling application on Windows 10. And now it does nothing.
**Run** can still handle *sysdm.cpl* but it seems that I cannot pass correctly the arguments.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure about the rundll32.exe path in win 10 ? Is it the same ?

Comment: I could see the application in the directory, yes. However, no luck trying to execute it directly from the command line. Guess the Run itself has been changed in a way, no idea. If I start it directly using Win + R, sysdm.cpl could be still started right away.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** This was auto-resolved somehow, perhaps a Windows Update. It is now working fine.